Multiple Callback Domains with SE API?
In order to use the API, you have to have Callback APIs.  They're not hard to implement, but there's still some headaches if you want to use more than one Callback endpoint.
For example, an application I'm running currently uses a callback URL of http://localhost:8888/callback which is simply going to return the data that was passed in. This callback server is handled by the application itself as a small Flask app that it starts and stops independently in threads.
However, another application (Postman, for example), needs to use its own auth callback point and won't have access to the same callback 'app' that an app in development uses.
Which begs the question: does the StackApps system permit us to specify multiple callback domains for these special cases?
And if not, am I resigned to using multiple registered applications instead, one for each potential callback domain?

Besides the administrative overhead, is there another downside to having to register multiple apps?

@rene when we're working with development-only and PLACEHOLDER posts for never-releasing-public-items-with-this-key, unless the system permits us to have more than one application tied to the same not really, except then I need proper secret key management and secrets management in my apps (which I already do via Infisical tooling but still).  More wondering if it's an intentional design restriction in the SE side of app registrations or not, since other toolings can enable multiple callback URLs/domains if needed.

last time I checked I could register multiple apps with the same question linked so you would only need one placeholder question.  I'll status-review to get SE dev eyes on this.

@rene thanks. In the interim I'll register multiple apps.  Since my existing app exists with special access at the moment, I'll have to poke SE to update the new client IDs as well.
